# MySQL performance between SELECT INTO OUTFILE vs creating file programmatically from result

Tags: mysql, database-administration, into-outfile

Is there any significant difference between saving records into file by executing `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` vs executing SELECT query within application and iterate through results and appending to file. Assuming server and client are on the same machine and result set is very big (milions of rows). Aside from overhead from iterating through result set in application code are there any significant differences in utilization of server resources?

Comment: Unless you know for certain your app can iterate the rows really quickly I would stick with SELECT INTO OUTFILE as this was created specificallyfor fast backup/restore processes and, in my experience, is incredibly fast.

Comment: It's not clear what you consider to be a "significant difference"—every application will have its own tolerances.  Even if you clarified that point, the best answer would be to try it yourself and benchmark the results—a whole host of issues might impact on the answer and, if ensuring that you stay within your application's performance tolerances is important to you, you will only obtain a definite answer through experimentation.

Comment: That said, it's reasonable to assume that (in most cases) @Giles is correct—the overhead of copying a resultset to a client, only for that client to then do what the MySQL server could have done itself from within its own native code, is likely to be more material than any (unlikely) performance advantage your own code might actually have.

Comment: The default (for some connectors) is to send the entire resultset before returning control to the client program.  `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` probably does it incrementally, thereby overlapping the reads and writes.